# Wrong behaviour of set<Vec3b>

Tags: c++, opencv, set, containers, std

I have a set of [Vec3b](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#vec) to hold posible RGB pixel values.

```
std::set<cv::Vec3b> used_colors;
```

But behaves weird:

```
used_colors.insert(cv::Vec3b(100, 255, 255));

// this returns 1 although (100, 0, 0) is NOT in the set
used_colors.count(cv::Vec3b(100, 0, 0));
```

**The value (100, 0, 0) is found because other value starting with 100 is already inserted in the set. Other values like (80, 0, 0) can not be found. This is obviously the wrong weird behaviour.**

I implemented the < comparision operator like this:

```
bool operator <(const cv::Vec3b &a, const cv::Vec3b &b) {
    if(a[0] < b[0])
        return true;

    if(a[0] > b[0]);
        return false;

    if(a[1] < b[1])
        return true;

    if(a[1] > b[1]);
        return false;

    if(a[2] < b[2])
        return true;

    if(a[2] > b[2]);
        return false;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Write some test code to exercise `operator<` in isolation. Once it's working correctly, move on to more complicated data structures. This is called "unit testing", and it's a fundamental tool for creating solid code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `operator<` is broken due to errant semicolons after several of the `if` statements.

Consider the inputs `a = Vec3b(100, 255, 255)` and `b = Vec3b(100, 0, 0)`. Because the `R` value of both is `100` the test makes it to

```
if(a[0] > b[0]);  // <-- notice the semicolon?
```

Because of that trailing semicolon the function unconditionally returns `false`. Due to the same reason, the comparison `b < a` also returns `false`; and `set::count` thinks the element already exists.

Get rid of the trailing semicolons and your comparison operator works as expected.

---

Instead of manually writing all those comparisons to do lexographical ordering, an easier, less error prone way is to use [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie)

```
bool operator<(const cv::Vec3b &a, const cv::Vec3b &b)
{
  return std::tie(a[0], a[1], a[2]) < std::tie(b[0], b[1], b[2]);
}
```

Comment: Gah, beat me to it by 1 minute. +1 for adding the bit about strict weak ordering.

Comment: @Yuushi I removed the bit about strict weak ordering. As written, the comparison operator will probably violate strict weak ordering for some other sets of inputs, but it isn't doing that for the example shown; so mentioning it is kind of a red herring.

Answer (score 3):

Your comparison function is stuffed, probably because you have `;` after a number of your `if` statements.

Even then, this is far more complex than it needs to be. `std::tie` makes this into a one-liner:

```
bool operator <(const cv::Vec3b &a, const cv::Vec3b &b) 
{
    return std::tie(a[0], a[1], a[2]) < std::tie(b[0], b[1], b[2]); 
}
```